# Relación circular Mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

espero me puedan ayudar ya que soy principiante y me encuentro con bastante dudas.

Tengo las siguientes tablas en base de datos: personas, servicios, persona_servicios, cobertura_especiales

Y las siguientes relaciones:

Un servicio puede tener una o más coberturas especiales: servicios ---> cobertura_especiales.

Una persona puede tener uno o mas servicios asociados (mucho a muchos). Por lo que obtengo la siguiente relación Personas --> Persona_servicios <--- Servicios.

Una persona con servicio asociado puede tener (es opcional) una o mas coberturas especiales según el servicio. Acá mi problema

Cuando intento relacionar a la persona con cobertura_especiales persona_servicio --> persona_servicio_cobertura_especial <--- cobertura_especiales.

Hasta ahora obtengo las siguientes relaciones:
Servicios --> cobertura_especiales,
Persona -->Persona_servicios <--- Servicios,
Persona_servicio -->Persona_servicio_cobertura_especial <-- Cobertura_especial <-- Servicios

Pero esto representa una relación circular y no encuentro como modelar de mejor forma, por favor ayúdenme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Juan gracias por tu respuesta, la contratación de coberturas especiales es opcional, la persona 1 puede tener el servicio 1 y las coberturas 1,2,3, la persona 2 puede tener el servicio 1 sin coberturas, la persona 2 puede tener el servicio 1 con solo la cobertura 1. La tabla que comentas usuario x servicio es la persona_servicio pero cada registro de esta tabla puede tener una o mas relaciones con coberturas especiales y es donde se crea la relación circular.

Comment: Olvidate la q plantee antes, esta es mejor y cubre todo, ahi siempre tenes acceso a los servicios y coberturas https://ibb.co/zXkRpWB podes crear que el primer registro de cobertura sea el Sin cobertura y ahi solucionas lo q planteas, la relacion esta siempre, mantenes la relacion de las tablas pero especificas que no tiene cobertura asociada

Comment: Para que me entiendas mejor https://ibb.co/GVZ4t45. La segunda opción esta mas cercana, pero como modelaría el caso que la persona 1 solo contrate servicio 1, sin ninguna cobertura?. La contratación de coberturas es opcional, la persona siempre contratará un servicio, es opcional que contrate una cobertura.

Comment: Porque hay tanto lio? porque no hay una tabla persona-coberturas?

Comment: Aca va mejor visualizado el modelo, fijate https://ibb.co/T11Z0N3

Comment: Juan.. tene en cuenta que tu solucion de una cobertura "sin cobertura", provoca que cuando el usuario tenga una cobertura efectivamente, entonces vas a tener que borrar esa no cobertura. Y siempre que el usuario se quede sin coberturas, vas a tener que agregar un registro "sin cobertura".. Estas solucionando un problema de sistema con algo raro en la DB...

Comment: hola @gbianchi gracias por tu respuesta, si agrego la relación persona_cobertura seguiré teniendo la relación circular https://ibb.co/3rVfPCB

Comment: Claro.. aca hay otro problema.. y es solo ver el problema por nombres y no por su uso. En una base de datos, lo importante es saber las reglas de negocios... No hay problemas en que tengas esas relaciones circulares.. siempre y cuando se respeten las reglas de negocio. Alguien te dijo que no podias hacer eso? por mas que dibujes como dibujes esto, siempre vas a tener esa relacion circular. Ahora, cual seria el problema de eso?

Comment: Las reglas del negocio son: 1. Una persona puede tener uno o más servicios, 2. Una persona, que contrate un servicio, puede o no tener coberturas adicionales. La persona siempre tendrá servicios asociados, es opcional que tenga coberturas. Persona 1 puede solo tener servicio 1, persona 2 puede tener servicio 1,2, y la cobertura 1 del servicio 2. Persona 3 puede tener servicio 1 y cobertura 1 y 2 de ese servicio. Una persona no puede tener solo cobertura. Solo tendrá cobertura si tiene un servicio.

Comment: Esta bien. y eso genera una referencia circular entre las tablas... no hay problemas con eso. o si?

Comment: No hay problema, pero en la documentación que he leído se hace énfasis en evitar este tipo de relaciones ya que pueden traer problemas, por eso busco información de como poder modelar de manera de que se evite esta relación circular.

Comment: Que documentacion? y que tipo de problemas? capaz tendriamos que empezar por ahi ;)

Comment: Algunos de los post que he revisado respecto al tema es este https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38655/Prevent-Circular-References-in-Database-Design  tambien he revisado esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521851/circular-relationship-in-database-design